# Is it possible to run an application on a single machine by choosing different .net frameworks at the run time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is it possible to run a application on a single machine by choosing different .net frameworks at the run time?

I asked it out of curiosity if it is possible?

Comment: In app.config you specify the .net version you wish to use. Once it is read during launch, you cannot change.

Comment: How do you mean "at the runtime". You mean, when the program already runs of before that?

Comment: maybe when we start the application.exe?

Comment: Bear in mind that any given machine will (currently) only have up to 4 actual runtimes installed - 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 and 4.0 (probably rare to encounter a machine with 1.0/1.1 in practice these days). Later framework versions within a given family *update* in place the CLR.

Comment: In practice there are only two runtime versions that you can have available on a machine.  v2.0.50727, normally updated to .NET 3.5SP1 and v4.0.30319, typically somewhere around 4.7.1 today when the machine is being maintained with Windows Update.  You don't get to choose, you can only specify the *minimum* version you need when you select the framework target in your project.  Ensuring the latest update is still compatible with the target you selected is Microsoft's job.

Answer (score 3):

Once the application is ran, you can't change the .NET Framework it uses.

Before the application runs, you can to some extend, but it depends on the build configuration. You can build a .NET application for a specific version of the CLR, with a minimum requirement on the .NET Framework version. It will pick the most appropriate .NET Framework version that is installed on that machine.

So an application built for the .NET 2.0 CLR runs on .NET 2.0, 3.5, etc. Then there is the .NET 4.0 CLR. You can force to run at least on 4.7.1, but that means it also runs on 4.7.2, or 4.8 for example. (I am leaving the old 1.0 and 1.1 CLR out of the picture here for now)

All 4.X are in-place updates on the .NET CLR 4. All 2.X and 3.X are in-place updates on the .NET CLR 2. You can only install one version of a framework for a specific CLR.